# How to truncate text vertically in css with flexbox

Tags: css

I'm trying to display the children of a div one below the other. All children have their own height but for the child with the .excerpt class, I would like a different behavior.
I want this div to take up the rest of the available space in its parent. It can therefore be high or very low depending on the size of the title above it.

this div contains text, how can I make this text truncated but not in the middle of a line?
I would also like to have the three points of the text-ellipsis

```
<div class="post-card-container" style="height: 600px;">

    <div class="content">
            <div class="media">
                    <a href="{{url}}" tabindex="-1">
                        Media zone
                    </a>
                    <hr>
            </div>
        <div class="post-data" style="flex: 0 0 50%;">
                <ul class="tags" aria-label="List of tags">
                        <li class="tag-container hidden">
                            <div class="tag-dot"></div>
                            <span class="tag-name">Security</span>
                        </li>
                </ul>
            <div class="title" style="flex-grow: 0;">
                <h2 title="{{title}}">Hello World this is my title and it is so big so </h2>
            </div>
                <p class="excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, unde. Ea, pariatur, vitae. Nemo doloremque iure non quod id ducimus, doloribus voluptate qui vero, assumenda vitae repellendus odit nam labore a rerum. Quasi blanditiis nam facere dolorem numquam doloremque beatae illo amet mollitia tempora perspiciatis reiciendis eaque repellendus aliquam rerum laudantium suscipit, culpa dolore ratione voluptatum! Assumenda deleniti cumque error eveniet pariatur, esse, quam ducimus consequatur perspiciatis adipisci doloribus rerum, laboriosam repudiandae tempore quis? Cum iusto tenetur perspiciatis quidem, nihil quod, repudiandae sed, inventore doloribus nam sapiente. Cum dolor saepe velit nulla, quos amet, nemo et. Tempora assumenda nulla repellat.
                </p>
            <div class="infos">
                <div class="authors-pic">
                    <div class="date">
                        <span>Date</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="read-more">
                <div class="read-more">
                    <a href="{{url}}" class="read">Read</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="../assets/js/custom-tags.js"></script>
```

I made an example on JSfidlle
[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/31o7cf05/22/)

I'm stuck on this problem

I have tried to use word-wrap and break word but i'm not able to have the good result